# get the servername + foldername (without script name)

Tags: asp.net

how to get the servername + foldername without containing the script name?

```
string filePath = Request.QueryString.Get("filepath");

string serverPath = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + "/";
string fullUrl = "http://" + serverPath + filePath;
Response.Write(fullUrl);
```

the above code is missing folder name.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/53/how-do-i-get-paths-and-url-fragments-from-the-httprequest-object) demonstrates how the parts of a HttpRequest break down. You could take the `Request.FilePath` and remove the final segment like so:

```
string directory = Request.FilePath.Remove(Request.FilePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do that, because HTTP is "blind" to what's a folder and what's a file.

You are probably familiar with URLs such as http://www.acme.com/products/view.asp but a completely valid URL could also be http://www.acme.com/products/view , so you can't differentiate a folder and a file name.

What you CAN do, provided that:

1. you know your application and know that it only runs *files* (as opposed to some routing mechanism that runs some logical piece of code, such as in MVC for example)
2. each file contains an extension

is to parse the path string on your own and look for *file.ext* pattern in the end of the path.